# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am newbie to JS and try to understand the Promise module, which I am using in my code. Below is the code [1], where I am trying to make it running somehow by providing several options of value parameter, actually I would want it to set to **cipher.encrypt(IP)** (which provide a format preserving encryption of IP, example: cipher.encrypt(15.10.23.4) = 20.24.35.9). 
The error I am receiving is following:

```
(node:9964) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
    at cache.<computed>.promise (/home/pooja/Documents/weiterbildung/promises/simple.js:13:23)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at doEncryption (/home/pooja/Documents/weiterbildung/promises/simple.js:8:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pooja/Documents/weiterbildung/promises/simple.js:29:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Thanks in advance,

[1]

```
const crypto = require('./fpe');                                                                                                                                                                                                   
const cipher = crypto({});                                                                                                                                                                                                         
const cache = {};                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

function doEncryption(IP) {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    if (!cache[IP]) {                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        cache[IP] = {                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            promise: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {                                                                                                                                                                            

                if(cipher.encrypt(IP)) {                                                                                                                                                                                           
                    const value = cipher.encrypt(IP) // cipher.encrypt(IP) returns an IP value, ex 10.10.12.12                                                                                                                      
                    cache[IP].value = value;                                                                                                                                                                                          
                    resolve(value);                                                                                                                                                                                                
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                else {                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                    resolve([]);                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            }), //end of promise                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        };                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        return cache[IP].promise;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    } else if (!cache[IP].value) {                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        return cache[IP].promise;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    return Promise.resolve(cache[IP].value);                                                                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

IP = "10.10.10.10"                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
let temp = doEncryption(IP)                                                                                                                                                                                                        

temp.then(value => console.log(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

`cache[IP]` does not yet exist inside the promise. Furthermore, your code should not work, because you assign a new object to `cache[IP]` with only the promise (without `value`).

One simple way to fix it, although maybe not the best one, could be:

```
cache[IP] = {}
cache[IP].promise = ...
```

Comment: few quires: 1. 'value', as I understand, is the state of the promise? if some function ends up running then value is SUCCESS (or the outcome of the function), if for some reason, function break/error, then value is REJECT? 2. What is actually the outcome of "cipher.encrypt(IP)", could not it be the success of the promise?

Comment: 1. then it would need to be `cache[IP].promise.value` if you are using a promise implementation that does this. But your `cache[IP]` is an object wrapping the promise, so `cache[IP].value` is another thing. 2. I have no idea what `cipher` is or `cipher.encrypt` does.

Comment: hmmm, thanks!. cipher.encrypt just take an IP parameter and reruns an IP. Example : cipher.encrypt(15.10.23.4) = 20.24.35.9